# Extract text by row using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to extract some datas from a page.

My page is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#">Orange</a>
    </div>
    <div class="color">
        <a href="#">orange</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#">Banana</a>
    </div>
    <div class="color">
        <a href="#">yellow</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract `title` and `color` by row.

This is my script:

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new
page = mechanize.get("#{url}")

page.search("div.row").each do |row|
    title = row.at("div.title a")
    email = row.at("div.color a")
    puts title
    puts email
end
```

It works but results are like this:

```
<a href="#">Orange</a>
<a href="#">orange</a>
<a href="#">Banana</a>
<a href="#">yellow</a>
```

I would like to extract only texts.
I try with `title = row.at("div.title a").text` but I have an error `undefined method 'text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Any idea? thx

Comment: If you're using Ruby 2.3+ you can use `title = row.at("div.title a")&.text`

Comment: I'm just tried with Ruby 2.3+ and it works. Can you explain what `&` does?